# Best way to get legs straight

Tags: rigging, sculpting

Working on a base model for a project and the automatic weights aren't working properly, tried using the pose brush method but the brush wont let me move just the legs. I am really trying to just straighten the legs and finger joints out. any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello it's hard to guess why it doesn't work, maybe explain more in detail and share your file?